# Bookmarks - sync OS X Firefox with iPhone / iPad Safari

Tags: firefox, sync, iphone, safari, ipad

I'm a Firefox user. I want to keep my bookmarks synchronised on all devices - desktop (Firefox Sync works great but just between my desktop instances), iPhone and iPad.

Since there is no FF for iPad and iPhone I recently switched to Chrome on desktop + phone + tablet. Google sync works great but Chrome consumes a lot of battery on Apple devices + because I'm a web developer I find Firefox firebug much better than the same tool that can be found in desktop Chrome (F12).

I would like to switch back to Firefox desktop + Safari for iPhone / iPad. I know that Apple released iCloud tool for syncing on Windows: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455 **but I'm not a Windows user**. I use only desktop Firefox on OS X.

**Is there a way to auto sync bookmarks between OSX Firefox and Safari iPhone / iPad devices**?
By saying sync I mean do it every time in background - I will add bookmark on FF and after a while it will appear on my bookmark bar in Safari on tablet. Not manually.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no.   This doesn't seem to be something that is possible.  It used to work with Xmarks, but Apple changed something that prohibited it from syncing properly and the Xmarks developers have either been unwilling or unable to get it working again.

When Yosemite was released,  I started using Safari just so I could start syncing my bookmarks with my iOS devices.  This is after being a Firefox user for the last several years.  I was just getting used to it and had nearly adjusted to new ways of doing what I wanted to do... but a couple of issues have suddenly appeared that are making me think of ditching it and moving over to Chrome (or Firefox).

I sent an email to Tim Cook (CEO @ Apple) stating my annoyance that OSX users are forced to use their browser if they want hassle-less bookmark syncing between Apple devices. No response. Not that I expected one.

Even more frustrating, Windows users using Chrome, Firefox or IE have tools to sync their bookmarks to iCloud.

Strikes me as a bit bizarre that OSX users are not given the same privilege.

If I start using a different browser - I guess when I bookmark a website, I will have to add it to Safari as well.  Bit of a  pain having to bookmark the same site twice in two browsers just to get them on my iOS devices.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox now provides sync functionality on multiple devices, which also includes open tabs.

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/sync/

There are a few things that currently don't work well with Firefox sync:

- Cannot close tabs open on computer from iPad (and vice versa)
- synced tabs can only be seen via history (on iPad), weird user experience
- bookmark sync is one-way (can only edit from computer)

If Firefox can have parity with Safari, I'd probably switch.